# Jenkins: Barchart Jenkins Cascade Plugin throws JSchException during release build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jsch

I've created an example project structure to test the [Barchart Plugin](https://github.com/barchart/barchart-jenkins-cascade-plugin/wiki/User-Manual).

```
-layout-project pom.xml
   -parent-module pom.xml
   -main-module pom.xml
   -dependency-module pom.xml
```

The layout and module projects are checked out from the configured git repo and the member and cascade projects are correctly built from the layout project. But when I trigger the release build  (selecting "Cascade Release" action on the project page and clicking "Submit") it throws the following exception:

```
FATAL: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://myusername@myhost/home/git/cascade-release.git: UnknownHostKey: myhost. RSA key fingerprint is 20:be:e9:3a:44:3d:cf:a8:24:00:e3:29:ab:7f:73:c5
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: myhost. RSA key fingerprint is 20:be:e9:3a:44:3d:cf:a8:24:00:e3:29:ab:7f:73:c5
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:805)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:345)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:117)

Caused: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://myusername@myhost/home/git/cascade-release.git: UnknownHostKey: myhost. RSA key fingerprint is 20:be:e9:3a:44:3d:cf:a8:24:00:e3:29:ab:7f:73:c5
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1201)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:128)

Caused: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://myusername@myhost/home/git/cascade-release.git: UnknownHostKey: myhost. RSA key fingerprint is 20:be:e9:3a:44:3d:cf:a8:24:00:e3:29:ab:7f:73:c5
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:135)
at com.barchart.jenkins.cascade.PluginScmGit.doFetch(PluginScmGit.java:153)

Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException
at com.barchart.jenkins.cascade.PluginScmGit.doFetch(PluginScmGit.java:155)
at com.barchart.jenkins.cascade.PluginScm$2.invoke(PluginScm.java:246)
at com.barchart.jenkins.cascade.PluginScm$2.invoke(PluginScm.java:221)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:997)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
at com.barchart.jenkins.cascade.PluginScm.scmCheckout(PluginScm.java:310)
at com.barchart.jenkins.cascade.CascadeLogic.process(CascadeLogic.java:346)
at com.barchart.jenkins.cascade.CascadeBuild$CascadeExecution.run(CascadeBuild.java:41)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
at com.barchart.jenkins.cascade.CascadeBuild.run(CascadeBuild.java:70)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

I've checked the `known_hosts` file in directory `<jenkins_home>/.ssh/` and it contains the fingerprint mentioned in the exception. Checking out from the git repo on the command line as user jenkins also works without any issues. Also this doesn't happen when releasing via Maven Release Plugin. So I guess it must be a plugin specific problem. Maybe a misconfiguration!?

Following is what I see on the server side

```
Mar  7 18:33:03 myhost sshd[29240]: 
error: Received disconnect from 192.168.0.9 port 46217:3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: 
UnknownHostKey: myhost. RSA key fingerprint is 20:be:e9:3a:44:3d:cf:a8:24:00:e3:29:ab:7f:73:c5 [preauth]
Mar  7 18:33:03 myhost sshd[29240]: Disconnected from 192.168.0.9 port 46217 [preauth]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the known_hosts file missed an entry of the remote host's (myhost) hash key in conjunction with the git user's public key. By adding the entry to the file I could verify with the command `ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f .ssh/known_hosts` that it now contains the expected fingerprint.